# What can I do with a slime hatched from a slime incubator (outdoors)?

Tags: stardew-valley

I just hatched my first slime egg from a slime incubator, outdoors and on my farm. I got excited in hopes that I would have a pet slime or that the slime would drop something over time like the other farm animals. However, it just attacked me and I ended up killing it.

Besides the Craft Master achievement, is there any use to incubating a slime outside of a slime hutch? I looked up the slime incubator on the stardew wiki but I couldn’t not find anything useful (unless I missed it).

Comment: I believe the answer is: No

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Not Really**

Slimes can be bred as explained on the [slime hutch wiki page](https://stardewvalleywiki.com/Slime_Hutch). Bred slimes have different loot tables and can be used to get certain items when killing them.

The only benefit to breeding them outdoors instead of the slime hutch is that you potentially have more space to do so.